# Reading content from URL with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read the content from a URL with Node.js but all I seem to get are a bunch of bytes. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. This is the code I currently have:

```
var http = require('http');

var client = http.createClient(80, "google.com");
request = client.request();
request.on('response', function( res ) {
    res.on('data', function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    } );
} );
request.end();
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

try using the on error event of the client to find the issue.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'google.com',
    path: '/'
}
var request = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(data);

    });
});
request.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
});
request.end();
```

Comment: This example works for most links. However I've found that this URL, https://au.yahoo.com/ gives back a buffer of data. Even when you convert to string, from buffer with different types of encoding its non readable. Any ideas?

Comment: @NickTaras see if my answer suit your need ;-p

Comment: Looks like a good solution. 

I this case Yahoo was serving the website with G-Zip compression. Another process was needed to unzip webpages before scrapping. Hope this helps anyone who has the same issue. Ttimasdf, I’ll run you code example and reply more specifically soon.

Answer (score 27):

HTTP and HTTPS:

```
const getScript = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const http      = require('http'),
              https     = require('https');

        let client = http;

        if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0) {
            client = https;
        }

        client.get(url, (resp) => {
            let data = '';

            // A chunk of data has been recieved.
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
            resp.on('end', () => {
                resolve(data);
            });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
};

(async (url) => {
    console.log(await getScript(url));
})('https://sidanmor.com/');
```

Answer (score 9):

the data object is a buffer of bytes.  Simply call `.toString()` to get human-readable code:

```
console.log( data.toString() );
```

reference: [Node.js buffers](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

Comment: Another option is to `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` Otherwise, I've found `npm install eyes` to be a useful tool for its `inspector()`.

Answer (score 9):

A slightly modified version of @sidanmor 's code. The main point is, not every webpage is purely ASCII, user should be able to handle the decoding manually (even encode into base64)

```
function httpGet(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const http = require('http'),
      https = require('https');

    let client = http;

    if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0) {
      client = https;
    }

    client.get(url, (resp) => {
      let chunks = [];

      // A chunk of data has been recieved.
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });

      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      resp.on('end', () => {
        resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
      });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}

(async(url) => {
  var buf = await httpGet(url);
  console.log(buf.toString('utf-8'));
})('https://httpbin.org/headers');
```