# how to get a document object from a given url in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, document

How can I using only Node.js API get a document of a given URL to work with.
Here is a snippet of what i come up with :

```
var needHttp  = require('http');

var getAllFromSite = function ( siteUrl, tag) 
{

var requestToURL = needHttp.get( siteUrl, function (responseFromURL) {

responseFromURL. SOMEHOWgetDOCUMENT...
  }); 

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading content from URL with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287297/reading-content-from-url-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found this, but still it needs DOMParser which I could't find:

```
function getSourceAsDOM(url)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
parser=new DOMParser();
return parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,"text/html");
}
```