# How does one get the html of a webpage from a url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, get-request

So this question I *thought* would be beyond simple. Yet after a solid hour of searching JavaScript and node js documentation and other questions on this site I've only found things that have to do with the same origin policy.

What I want is to make a simple request to a url and read it's html/source code. This is to query a wiki and return the top link from the search results. I can handle dealing with the html myself, but I am absolutely dumbfounded as to how to get the html. I know how to do it very easily with Lua socket in a single line, which is how I did this when making a twitch bot, but now that I am adapting it to discord I'm coding it in JavaScript, and I am not as well versed in JavaScript.

Does anybody know how to go about this?

My current code:

```
function SearchWiki(query) {
    console.log("I was called, I guess")
    var options = {
        path: encodeURI(query),
        method: "GET"
    }
    var request = http.request("http://pm-challenge.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=", options, function (res) {
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log(data);  
        });
    });
    request.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
    request.end();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287297/reading-content-from-url-with-node-js

Comment: If you mean to be able to request it from a browser then it will really depend on your requirements.  In modern chrome you can use `fetch` with `no-cors` options.

If you have to support many types of browsers then the best option is to create an end point to proxy the request.  Then you can have it return whatever you want and not have to deal with browsers.

Comment: Looking into these links, thanks guys, will post back in a bit

Comment: @Austio — The question is tagged [tag:node.js] and browsers are not mentioned. Even if the question was about browsers, if the `no-cors` option was used, then he wouldn't be able to read the response! That's the point of `no-cors` (to silently fail at things CORS permission is required for instead of throwing an error).

Comment: @AdamH When I use the code in the answer to that question I get the following output: `Moved to <a href="http://pm-challenge.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=">http://pm-challenge.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=</a>`

Comment: Sounds like you got a 301 (moved) code, try using the URL they suggest.

Comment: @AdamH Oh, I see. Alright I changed my url and just made the path in the options the search query itself. My issue now is a 400 bad request. How do I fix that?

Comment: @warspyking — We have no way of knowing what request you are sending or what the server you are making the request to considers bad about it.

Comment: @warspyking fix the request?

Comment: I've edited code into my question @AdamH

Comment: Odds are it's you query parameter, try using encodeURI()

Comment: @AdamH Same issue

Comment: What's in the query parameter?

Comment: @AdamH "pre-hooktail%%20pit"

Comment: Take a look here to see what you are doing wrong with the options and passing the URL: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179495/discussion-between-warspyking-and-adam-h).

Comment: the request callback function takes 3 params. The thrid param is the HTML body.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request