# Load external JavaScript libraries/scripts from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build a console application using JavaScript/Node.js, the following script.js throws an `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` upon compilation:

```
//user input from command line
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
 input: process.stdin,
 output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Would you like to see which Car Types are available? Please type yes/no ", function(answer) {
// if yes, print search results to console in descending price order 
if (answer === 'yes'){

var results= "";
$.getJSON("https://techtest.rideways.com/dave/?pickup=3.410632,-2.157533&dropoff=3.410632,-2.157533", function(data){
results = JSON.parse(data);
}); 

console.log("The following Car Types are available:", results.options['car_type'], " - ", results.options['price']);
}else{
console.log("No worries, have a nice day!");
}
rl.close();
});
```

As shown in this post; [ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268881/referenceerror-is-not-defined) I'm hoping its because I'm missing the JS libraries.

Is there a way I can call the JS libraries inside my script.js without creating a separate HTML file? As I'm not building a front end web application therefore don't see the point in creating a HTML file?

Comment: You're using Nodejs. Use jquery with require. Like var $ = require('jquery');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` looks like it was a copy/paste from some jQuery code. Instead of jQuery, axios will get the job done in Node and in a browser. [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) is an http request library with promises. First, add the package to the project: `$ npm i -s axios`.

Example get request: ([run it on repl.it](https://repl.it/@median_man/SO-axios-example))

```
const axios = require('axios');

main();

function main() {
  return exampleRequest().then(renderResponseData)
}

function exampleRequest() {
  const url = 'https://techtest.rideways.com/dave/?pickup=3.410632,-2.157533&dropoff=3.410632,-2.157533';

  return axios.get(url)
}

function renderResponseData(response) {
  console.log(response.data)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Node.js code, you don't typically need to use jQuery, but if you do want to it's available as an `npm` module. You'd install it (`npm install jquery`) and then `require` it just like you `require`d `readline` in your code. Full details (since jQuery expects a DOM environment) [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129032/157247).

**But**, there's no need for jQuery here. Use [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) or [`https.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback) or similar instead. I doubt `$.getJSON` will even work in Node.js.

Comment: Thank you, I will stick with `require` for now but will look into `http.request`. I'm getting `$.getJSON is not a function` error although I have installed get-json via `npm get-json`

Comment: @Sara - Really, don't try to use jQuery for network operations on Node.js. Out of curiousity I just gave it a go, and it complained about trying to do a cross-origin request from origin `null`. jQuery just isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: I understand but, it's just I'm short on time here and learning how to use `http.request` will take some time

Comment: @Sara - If you're short on time, **definitely** don't try to use the wrong tool for the job. Just look for examples, [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287297/reading-content-from-url-with-node-js).

Comment: Thank you for the link I will definitely check them out in my spare time! I'd like to learn more about Node.js.