# readFileSync not reading URL as file

Tags: node.js

Using [api/url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) and [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) as in the guide:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let myURL = new URL('/ns/oa', 'https://www.w3.org/');
let contents = fs.readFileSync(myURL).toString();
console.log(contents)
```

ERROR: ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME

---

**NOTE**: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6287297/287948) is similar and good clue for readers (!), but it is not a solution to my problem, that was only to use URL as "real URL" (not collapsing the concept to `file//`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading content from URL with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287297/reading-content-from-url-with-node-js)

Comment: @Mureinik, hum... **No**, it is not a duplicate... I need `readFileSync` and the simplest sync use, as in PHP's file_get_contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just quoting the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_url_object_support): Note the quotes in **bold**

> URL object support
>   Added in: v7.6.0
>
> For most fs module functions, the path or filename argument may be passed as a WHATWG URL object. **Only URL objects using the file: protocol are supported.**

Simply put, `https:` protocol is not supported

Example.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileUrl = new URL('file:///tmp/hello');

fs.readFileSync(fileUrl);
```

Comment: oops, ok... Well, it is a "false URL" (!!)...  **no simple `file_get_contents()`**  equivalent for NodeJs.

Comment: well the equivalent is the one in the link above.

Answer (score 3):

`fs.readFile(Sync)` as well as all other `fs` api only deals with local files.

`URL` api can accept local files using the `file://` protocol, and that's the meaning of using `URL` in `fs.readFile`.

If you need to get a file from the web you need to use `http/https` api, specifically `request` or similar to read the contents of the file/url you want. Something along this line:

```
const https = require('https');
let myURL = new URL('/ns/oa', 'https://www.w3.org/');
let body = [];
https.request(myURL, res=>{
  // XXX verify HTTP 200 response
  res.on('data', chunk=>body.push(chunk));
  res.on('end', ()=>console.log(Buffer.concat(body).toString()));
}).end()
```

Comment: Hi, seems good solution, but not working, "Error: Cannot find module 'request'"... Hum.. Seems it is not a "native solution", generates dependency and not so reliable code. Can you cite module reference?

Comment: there you go (https://github.com/request/request), request is a wrapper on the native http.request with many more features, I'll change the answer to use native request

Comment: Hi, thanks (!).  There are many non-native soutions, the most popular ones seems *request* and *axios*... You can keep (to add) suggestions and its source-code, no problem. I am voting-up, but the I can't  click accept-answer (as the main) because the first was also correct... But yours is also a good answer (!).

Comment: np, I'm still new to being active on SO (so it takes a long time to write answer)