# readFileSync can't find file from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to download a file (without saving it) and convert it, but readFileSync throws an error that the file can't be found: `"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1631452514756x615162562554826200/testdoc.txt'"`

Code:

```
var path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const file_x = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1631452514756x615162562554826200/testdoc.txt';
var filename = path.basename(file_x);

const FileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(file_x);
const fileParam = {
    value: FileBuffer,
    options: {
      filename: filename,
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream'
    }
};

console.log(fileParam);
```

And I get the error the file can't be found... The URL is working OK, do I need to do something else to download from URL ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [readFileSync not reading URL as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665026/readfilesync-not-reading-url-as-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [`fs`](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-fs-module) only reads files, not URLs. Alternatively, you can use a package like [`axios`](https://npmjs.com/package/axios). Axios allows you to make HTTP requests within `node.js`.

Example usage:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1631452514756x615162562554826200/testdoc.txt').then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try looking for similar questions? For example, [readFileSync not reading URL as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665026/readfilesync-not-reading-url-as-file/55665383). There it is clearly stated that the `fs` API only deals with local files.

You will need to use the `https` module to stream the file.

Comment: Don't add questions into solutions. Instead [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)