# Scrape website/domain and check of URLs exist of a certain format - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, dns

I want to write some JavaScript, which checks if a domain, includes a certain set of URLS.

For example:

1. Check if http://www.mywebsite.com/
2. Includes URLS which begin with http://www.mywebsite.com/123

Is it possible to do this in JavaScript?

I've written something similar, which finds URLs on a given page.  But I actually, want to check on an entire domain...

```
let offerLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="mywebsite.com/offers"]');

for (let index = 0; index < offerLinks.length; index++) {
   const element = offerLinks[index];
   console.log("These are all the looped offer links - " + element); 
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are writing a node.js application. (Because of same-site security limitation the check you want to do would be locked to the hosting only website in case of a Browser script).

Assumed you are writing a Node app the operation you want to do is called "scraping" (a really simple version of scraping). There are many libraries for Node that can help you. One of this is [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/).

First thing load url content into a string, you can copy code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287297/reading-content-from-url-with-node-js) for that.

Second parse the string with cheerio and extract the links as you need, something like:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load(webPageLoadedContent)
$('a').filter(function(i, el) {
  return $(this).attr('href').includes('mywebsite.com/offers')
})
```

This is the procedure for a single web page. To expand to a whole website you have to recurvely apply it to every url you find (filtering based on site name).

Comment: Hey @fabiano Taioli - thank you for the answer. I will check this out!  I actually wanted to do this with Vanilla JS, as I wanted to build chrome extension. I'm assuming I'll still be able to build a chrome extension, after compiling/building with Node?  Is running on node the only way to scrap a website using javascript?

Comment: I think you can do it in chrome extension but you have to request the needed permissions [read here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)