# getting the link to specific .xml from sitemap.xml of a website

Tags: node.js, xml, web-scraping

i have a website sitemap.xml and the structure is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
            <loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap/Main-8531739688368880386.xml</loc>
        </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
            <loc>https://www.example.com/sitemap/Product-8073944469920756310.xml</loc>
        </sitemap>
    </sitemapindex>
```

i get the above sitemap.xml only after i load [www.example.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml). i want to get the sitemapindexed items there as they keep changing, thereby grabbing the `<loc>` tags after [www.example.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml) has loaded , so as i can work with the Product-8073944469920756310.xml link there.

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can grab it using xpath. For example:

```
let
     xpath = require('xpath'), 
     dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser,
     xml = `your xml above`,
     doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml),
     nodes = xpath.select("//*[local-name()='loc']/text()", doc)
console.log(nodes[1].data)
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/sitemap/Product-8073944469920756310.xml
```

Comment: the thing is i get that xml after loading example.com/sitemap.xml. and the sitemaps indexed there always keeps changing. So i need to load example.com/sitemap.xml first then grab those locations from there. (updated the main question to make it clear.)

Comment: @XenaDAux The answer assumes you have your xml string loaded (as was the case in your original question). How to get your xml from a url - that is a different question, and probably should be posted separately. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287297/reading-content-from-url-with-node-js

Comment: this solution will work only if i paste the entire xml as static. i need visit the link example.com/sitemap.xml and then work on it through a headless browser if possible. due to the fact that the items there keeps being updated.

Comment: ty for the help. i scraped the page with puppeteer first then with the xml outputted as string i can use this snippet to parse it then. appreciate the help.